# active_model_serializers not working in rails-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I have been looking around a lot and have not found a solution.

I have a rails-API application
and simple model, controller, and serializer

but when I try to get index route I get standard rails JSON not serialized.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class TagSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
end

class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Tag.all
  end
end
```

I get:

```
[
  tag: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'kifla'
  },
  tag: 
 .....
```

I want:

```
[
  { id: 1, title: 'kifla'},
  { .....
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to *disable the root element* of your json output.

How this is achieved may depend on which version of `active_model_serializers` you're using.

In `0.9.x`, you could do something like this in a Rails initializer:

```
# Disable for all serializers (except ArraySerializer)
ActiveModel::Serializer.root = false

# Disable for ArraySerializer
ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.root = false
```

Or simply, in your controller action:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Tag.all, root: false
  end
end
```

For more info, here are links to relevant sections of the README pages of recent versions.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#disabling-the-root-element

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable#disabling-the-root-element

--

Note, please make sure also that you're actually including the code that handles serialization, as ActionController::API does not by default. For example,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Serialization
end
```

Comment: it seems that that was not the only problem i have, accept the root elemnt problem, my serializer is not called at all, like it does not exists. I have been searching the web and I have found few stuff people did but non of them helped me.

Comment: The next answer by Zamith solves the problem of the serializers not getting hooked into the rendering step, and it would probably be worth editing this answer to include it.

Comment: Simply adding `include ActionController::Serialization` did it for me (Rails 5 API-only).

Answer (score 32):

That's because the serialization is not loaded by default in rails-api. You have to do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ::ActionController::Serialization
end
```

Comment: Yup, this was the issue.

Comment: Exactly, if your ApplicationController inherits from ActionController::API, then you should manually include serialization

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, when using the most recent rails-api 4.2.0beta

Serializers didn't get picked up. I downgraded rails-api to 4.1.5 and it worked.
Don't forget to remove

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
```

from config/application.rb it will raise an error in versions prior to 4.2.0

Comment: This is now fixed in 0.9.3. You can read the Github thread here: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/641

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the latest version, it seems that you can't set the default adapter anymore according to this:

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1683

The workaround is to use

```
    render json: object_to_render, adapter: :json
```

Also, it's not necessary to add this anymore:

```
    include ::ActionController::Serialization
```

It's frustrated to see how Rails api keeps changing version to version without detailed documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting your browser, if you recently added the serializer