# Rails active_model_serializers not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, active-model-serializers, ruby-on-rails-6.1

This is my first time to use **active_model_serializers** gem, I have been looking around the documentation and have not found a solution.

I have followed all the [Getting Started](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/getting_started.md) documentation but when I try to get the serialized record I get standard rails JSON not serialized record.

I found a similar thread in SO : [active_model_serializers not working in rails-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192463/active-model-serializers-not-working-in-rails-api), in this thread many people said that we need to manually add `include ActionController::Serialization` in our ApplicationController. I also have followed, but nothing work. Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Controller :

```
class AdministratorsController < ApplicationController
    def login
        @administrator = Administrator.find_by(username: params[:username])

        if @administrator && @administrator.authenticate(params[:password])
            token = encode_token({ administrator_id: @administrator.id })
            render json: { administrator: @administrator, token: token }
        else
            render json: { error: 'Username atau Passowrd anda salah !' }, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end
end
```

Serializer :

```
class AdministratorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :full_name, :username
end
```

Actual Response :

```
{
    "administrator": {
        "id": 1,
        "full_name": "Kevin Jayden Wivano",
        "username": "kevin",
        "password_digest": "blablabla",
        "created_at": "2021-10-23T15:36:15.793Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-23T15:56:27.782Z"
    },
    "token": "theJWTtoken"
}
```

Expected Response :

```
{
    "administrator": {
        "id": 1,
        "full_name": "Kevin Jayden Wivano",
        "username": "kevin"
    },
    "token": "theJWTtoken"
}
```

Comment: This gem is not maintained anymore and even the maintainers recommend using something else now. I see you have found blueprinter, that is a very nice gem. This one is ok too if you want a different approach https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
    render json: {:administrator => AdministratorSerializer.new(@administrator).to_h}
```

In place Of:

```
    render json: { administrator: @administrator, token: token }
```